# Can one say the energy stored in the rotating flywheel as strained energy due to hoop stress?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

Can one say the energy stored in the rotating  flywheel as strained energy due to induced hoop stress because of rotation?

i mean if flywheel set in rotation omega, two thing will happen

1. It will store rotation energy also called as inertia energy.
2. Hoop stress will be generated because of rotation.

in order to correlate both does can we assume that when a flywheel is set in rotation the rotational energy will stored as strained energy due hoop stress generation?\

please do the need full. my doubt is is there any proportional relation between hoop stress and stored energy?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, hoop stress will add (a little) to the energy stored in a flywheel: if your flywheel were a pair of masses on radial springs, you can see this most clearly. Obviously if the pair of masses rotates quickly, the springs will expand. This will lead to a larger moment of inertia of the system (masses further from the origin) which means that for the same rotational speed, there will be a greater angular momentum and more stored energy in the rotation as well as in the springs.

For the simple example given, if the masses are $\frac{m}{2}$ each and the springs have a spring constant of $k$, initial length $r$, then if we rotate the system at velocity $\omega$ the energy stored will be the sum of rotational and elastic energy. First we compute the new radius

$$F_{spring}=m\omega^2 r'=k(r'-r)\\
r' = \frac{r}{1-\frac{m\omega^2 }{k}}$$

The elastic energy will be $\frac12 k (r'-r)^2$ and the rotational energy $\frac12 m r'^2 \omega^2$. I will leave it up to you to figure out their relative magnitudes as you change $k$.

Comment: thanks Mr.Floris.. it is indeed information for me.. thanks alot

Comment: hello Floris ...i do accept your explanation,but i am bit interested in the case of solid flywheel same as in case of single cylinder IC engine... because as explained by you we have know values of K..i mean spring constant, but in case of solid flywheel this K value is difficult to arrive for the given shape...so could you explain me what will be in the case of solid flywheel..

Answer (score 0):

No: the energy stored in a flywheel's rotational momentum has nothing to do with any energy stored in stretching of the flywheel's circumference. It's just like the energy of an object moving linearly, which has nothing to do with the energy stored in any simultaneous stretching of the object. Just because both may happen at the same time doesn't mean they're linked.